# Перенаправление 301

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Всем доброго времени суток! Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно настраивать 301 редирект?

проверил сайт по seo через определенную программу, выходит данная ошибка:

Используйте перенаправления 301 для направления трафика на URL-адреса с тем же доменом и поддоменом (субдомен с www и без www).

буду Очень признателен!

Answer (score 2):

Видимо речь идет о чем то подобном

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [L,R=301]
```

в таком случае при заходе на [www.domain.com/page.html](http://www.domain.com/page.html) вас перенаправит с 301м редиректом на domain.com/page.html